# Storing the blank file using Django and Python

Tags: python, django

I need some help. I need to save the `.csv` file into local folder using Python but its storing the blank file. I am explaining my code below.

> views.py:

```
report = Reactor.objects.all()
filename = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.csv'
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+filename
with open(settings.FILE_PATH + filename, 'w') as csv_file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    response_writer = csv.writer(response)
    file_writer.writerow(['Name', 'Status', 'Date'])
    response_writer.writerow(['Name', 'Status', 'Date'])
    for rec in report:
        if rec.status == 1:
            status = 'Start'
        if rec.status == 0:
            status = 'Stop'
        if rec.status == 2:
            status = 'Suspend'
        file_writer.writerow([rec.rname, status, rec.date])
        response_writer.writerow([rec.rname, status, rec.date])
return response
```

> settings.py:

```
FILE_PATH = os.getcwd()+'/upload/'
```

Here I am also downloading the file and I need to save that file into folder but here some blank file is storing. Please help me.

Comment: Well, you opened a file for writing - and then didn't write anything into it.  What possible result could you expect, other than a blank file?

Comment: Actually I need to save that `str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.csv'` file Can you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jasonharper said you are only writing the csv data to the response and not to the file on the disk. Start by creating another writer object:

```
file_writer = csv.writer(open(settings.FILE_PATH + filename, 'w'))
```

Now each time you call writerow on `writer` also do this for the `file_writer`:

```
file_writer.writerow(['Name', 'Status', 'Date'])
...
file_writer.writerow([rec.rname, status, rec.date])
```

It is best to use the `with` statement to let python automatically close the file:

```
with open(settings.FILE_PATH + filename, 'w') as csv_file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    response_writer = csv.writer(response)

    file_writer.writerow(['Name', 'Status', 'Date'])
    response_writer.writerow(['Name', 'Status', 'Date'])
    for rec in report:
        ...

        file_writer.writerow([rec.rname, status, rec.date])
        response_writer.writerow([rec.rname, status, rec.date])

return response
```

Comment: Then where I will save the file.

Comment: The file will be saved to `settings.FILE_PATH + filename` as it is the first argument to the `open` function.